# Proving that a complex function blows up near a pole

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

I am struggling to prove that if $z_0$ is a pole of order $k$ of $f(z)$, then $\lim_{z \to z_0} |f(z)| = \infty$, could anyone help point me in the correct direction?

Comment: If the limit doesn't blow up, will you call $z_0$ a pole? I leave it to you to recall the definition of a pole

Comment: The definition given is regarding a finite number of negative powers in the Laurent series, from this how can we show my question?